# need a batch to search in all available drives and display a file which is in one or more places

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file, cmd

Need a windows batch file to search in all available drives and display a file which is in one or more places.

How to do below thing using an array?

my scenario:

1. check for `drive:/programfiles/test/config.xml` in all available drives(a,b,..z).
2. if file exits in one or more place ,list all the discovered files in

   1. `c:/programfiles/test/config.xml`
   2. `e:/programfiles/test/config.xml`
      in this way it has to check each and every drive and has to display if file is there.
3. then i have to choose an option from the list ie 2 to use `e:/programfiles/test/config.xml`.

so it should return me u have selected  `e:/programfiles/test/config.xml`.

Vijai K

Comment: some people are saying, cmd aka Batch doesn't have arrays, Batch only has data structures that looking like arrays ('pseudo-arrays'?)

Comment: @joeyi've tried `@echo off 
setlocal 
for %%i in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do ( 
rem for /f "tokens=*" %%a in 
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d %%i:\init.xml ') do ( 
set "foundFile=%%i" & goto found 
)) 
rem GOTO end_of_file
goto file_not_found 
:found 
echo File found - %foundFile%` this is returning C:\Program Files (x86)\tester2.0\assets\xml\init.xml but i've same file d: also.this script should do loop and list all the available init.xml file.so that i can select one from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over lists of items with `for`:

```
for %%D in (C D E F G H I ... X Y Z) do
```

You can check for a file existing with `if exist filename`:

```
if exist %%D:\programfiles\test\config.xml
```

And use `echo` to output text:

```
echo %%D:\programfiles\test\config.xml
```

This should give you enough to write the batch file yourself.